Is it possible to have weightened (for every layer) gradient?
Imagine having pretrained network(resnet, ...) If we want to train for new classification task we change last layer and maybe freeze some first leayers. But what if we have another network that weigths gradient for each layer ( for example for conv layer num6 the gradient multiplies by 5, for linear layer num2 the gradient multiplies by -2 etc..) and this network is also trainable. But i don't know how to add weights of such netwok to comp graph
list_ = []
for param in resnet.parameters():
    add = torch.ones(param.shape[0], requires_grad = True)
    list_.append(MultiplyLayer(multiplier = add))

another_nn = nn.ModuleList(list_)

...

for index, param in enumerate(resnet.parameters()):
    param.data += another_nn[index](-lr * param.grad)

This method obviously loses information about the multipling coefficient
for _, param in enumerate(another_nn):
    print(param.multiplier.grad)
-> None
-> None
-> None
-> None
...

